# That content has been temporarily disabled

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have noticed recently that I am getting the following error message a lot when trying to perform a variety of things;

[image]

It looks pretty obvious what it could mean, but I'm getting it in some situations that would verify my guessed meaning, and then some instances that really don't make any sense...

The first time I saw this message was during the Tixx dungeon, for Wintersday, when trying to use any action on my action bar while carrying 'plant food' during the third phase of the dungeon. (The action bar only has one item on it in slot one, which is to root an enemy with a vine).

Today, however, I got this error while trying to interact with Lionguard Lyns, the announcer in Lion's Arch who asked for donations;

[image]

Previously, interacting with this NPC would simply tell you to go and speak to another NPC, which is where my confusion comes from.

Am I getting this error message due to some form of game file corruption or it ArenaNet disabling random content for some reason or another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arena Net uses this message to disable specific content, usually if they've found an exploit or the like (for a while, this would pop up every time you killed a Risen Grub). So for the two announcements in Tixx's workshop (Ball of Ooze does the same), it's likely there was some major bug in using those abilities.

Lionguard Lynns is a different, simpler, beast. From the patch notes:

> Commendation vendor Lionguard Lyns is restocking her goods and is not accepting commendations at this time. She will begin accepting commendations again soon.

Why ANet decided to disable her in this way, instead of just removing the dialog options, is a mystery.